# preg_match get a part of text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**i have this text....**

====================================================

Australian Medical Association president Steve Hambleton said on Monday any change which would deter people from seeing a doctor.

"I think we've got to identify what the problem is that we're trying to solve," Dr Hambleton said.

On Sunday federal Health Minister Peter Dutton refused to end speculation that the proposal had the government's support, only saying he was committed to ensuring the health system was "sustainable and accessible to the future".

"We won't be commenting on speculation around what the Commission of Audit may or may not recommend," Mr Dutton said in a statement.

The report predicts that the volume of "GP services" would decline by 3 per cent a year if co-payment was introduced, slowing the growth in Medicare Benefits Schedule outlays from July 2014.

================================================

***I want to match all quotes in the above paragraph,***

**Expected Result:**

1. ''I think we've got to identify what the problem is that we're trying to solve,'' Dr Hambleton said.
2. "We won't be commenting on speculation around what the Commission of Audit may or may not recommend," Mr Dutton said in a statement.

i am using this code , but not working..

```
$match = array();

preg_match_all("/\'\'(.*)\'\'/i", $str, $match);
```

if it's possible with regex i will use that, but the problem is that how i can grab Quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All quotes that are declared with **said** verb:

```
\B"[^"]+"(?=.+?said)[^.]+.
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/cW5gM8)

You should use it with multi-line & case insensetive (optional) flags:

```
preg_match_all('/\B"[^"]+"(?=.+?said)[^.]+./mi', $text, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide what you have under "Expected Result." However please note that it doesn't match all quotes in your provided text such as "sustainable and accessible to the future". I know you didn't have these in your expected results, I'm just clarifying that they are omitted and this is the reason my solution doesn't provide them.

```
$text = <<<EOD
====================================================

Australian Medical Association president Steve Hambleton said on Monday any change which would deter people from seeing a doctor.

"I think we've got to identify what the problem is that we're trying to solve," Dr Hambleton said.

On Sunday federal Health Minister Peter Dutton refused to end speculation that the proposal had the government's support, only saying he was committed to ensuring the health system was "sustainable and accessible to the future".

"We won't be commenting on speculation around what the Commission of Audit may or may not recommend," Mr Dutton said in a statement.

The report predicts that the volume of "GP services" would decline by 3 per cent a year if co-payment was introduced, slowing the growth in Medicare Benefits Schedule outlays from July 2014.

================================================
EOD;

$matches = null;
preg_match_all('#"[ a-zA-Z,\']+"[ a-zA-Z,\']+\.#m', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches); // $matches[0] contains array of all matched quotes
```

?>

Comment: Sorry about the color formatting in the above code. It's due to my use of [heredoc](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of working code:

```
$str = <<<EOT
Australian Medical Association president Steve Hambleton said on Monday any change which would deter people from seeing a doctor.

"I think we've got to identify what the problem is that we're trying to solve," Dr Hambleton said.

On Sunday federal Health Minister Peter Dutton refused to end speculation that the proposal had the government's support, only saying he was committed to ensuring the health system was "sustainable and accessible to the future".

"We won't be commenting on speculation around what the Commission of Audit may or may not recommend," Mr Dutton said in a statement.

The report predicts that the volume of "GP services" would decline by 3 per cent a year if co-payment was introduced, slowing the growth in Medicare Benefits Schedule outlays from July 2014.
EOT;
$match = array();

preg_match_all('/(?:[^.?!\s][^.?!"]+)?"[^"]*"[^.?!"]*[.?!]"?/i', $str, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

This produces:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(98) ""I think we've got to identify what the problem is that we're trying to solve," Dr Hambleton said."
    [1]=>
    string(228) "On Sunday federal Health Minister Peter Dutton refused to end speculation that the proposal had the government's support, only saying he was committed to ensuring the health system was "sustainable and accessible to the future"."
    [2]=>
    string(132) ""We won't be commenting on speculation around what the Commission of Audit may or may not recommend," Mr Dutton said in a statement."
    [3]=>
    string(190) "The report predicts that the volume of "GP services" would decline by 3 per cent a year if co-payment was introduced, slowing the growth in Medicare Benefits Schedule outlays from July 2014."
  }
}
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `(?:[^.?!\s][^.?!"]+)?` Allow the sentence to start with non-quoted material. Start with a non-space, non-punctuation character, then match non-punctuation, non-quote characters.
- `"[^"]*"` A quote, non-quote characters, and another quote.
- `[^.?!"]*` Optionally, more non-quote, non-punctuation characters.
- `[.?!]"?` A final punctuation mark and, optionally, a final quotation mark.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LdiZqYkE407oGXiG)

Known issues: It won't match sentences with more than one quote or a period before the start of the quote. For example, this: `Mr. Brown said, "I think," then continued, "therefore I am."`

**EDIT:** This fixes the above issues:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=[^.?!\s])(?:(?:(?:Mrs?|Dr|Rev)\.\s|[^.?!"])*?"[^"]*?[^.?!]")+(?:(?:(?:Mrs?|Dr|Rev)\.\s|[^.?!"])*?(?:"[^"]*?[.?!]"?|[.?!]))/i', $str, $match);
```

It matches each of the above sentences and also produces a match for this sentence:

> Mr. Brown said, "I think," then continued as Mr. Green fidgeted, "therefore I am."

Demo:

```
(?=[^.?!\s])(?:(?:(?:Mrs?|Dr|Rev)\.\s|[^.?!"])*?"[^"]*?[^.?!]")+(?:(?:(?:Mrs?|Dr|Rev)\.\s|[^.?!"])*?(?:"[^"]*?[.?!]"?|[.?!]))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VjtBtprj_ONsfnqs)